# Neo4J: List data type conversion

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

A string is stored in a node:

```
match (r:Reply)--(n:TRANS)
return split(toInteger(n.content), " ")
```

As you can imagine, the 'toInteger' method in the second line is incorrectly positioned - and returns exceptions.

Is there a method in Cypher where one can convert a list of Strings into a list of integers?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to convert the numbers in a space-separated string to integers (in separate rows):

```
WITH '123 456 789' AS content
UNWIND SPLIT(content, " ") AS i
RETURN TOINTEGER(i) AS value;
```

And here is an example of how to get the integers in an array:

```
WITH '123 456 789' AS content
RETURN [i IN SPLIT(content, " ") | TOINTEGER(i)] AS values;
```

Comment: You can also use the [extract](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-extract) function `extract(value IN SPLIT(content, " ")| TOINTEGER(value)) AS i`